# Calculations against each row in a table in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new to SQL and I am sure this must be a common problem but I could not find a solution. So if you can atleast point me in the right direction it will be great.

I have a table called forecasts that contains a list of all the forecasts for products where products is a separate table containing a list of all the unique products with number serving as an identifier.

I am trying to calculate the average forecast for all the products based on the forecasts table

**forecasts table**

```
CREATE TABLE forecasts
(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  month DATE,
  quantity INTEGER,
  extract_date DATE,
  product_number VARCHAR,
  final BOOLEAN DEFAULT false
);
```

I am currently using the following query and iterating over each item in ruby on rails to generate the average forecast

**Single product average query**

```
WITH three_month_forecast AS (
  SELECT product_number, month, sum(quantity) as forecast
  FROM forecasts
  WHERE extract_date >= '2016-08-01'::DATE - INTERVAL '1 month'
    AND extract_date < '2016-08-01'::DATE
    AND final = TRUE
    AND month >= '2016-08-01'::DATE
    AND month < '2016-08-01'::DATE + INTERVAL '3 months'
   AND product_number = '100046119'
 GROUP BY product_number, month, extract_date
 ORDER BY month
)

SELECT avg(forecast) FROM three_month_forecast
```

There are around 100k items in the products database so it is taking a while to complete in rails. It should be much faster in SQL without having to iterate over each item separately.

Any idea how I can run the average query for all the items in the products database so that it returns a table looking something like

product_number | average_forecast

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

**Edit**

A sqlfiddle containing a sample calculation for one product
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ab1637/2

**Edit 2**

Adding a query explain. The table does not currently have any indices

```
Aggregate  (cost=15074.16..15074.17 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=432.189..432.190 rows=1 loops=1)
      CTE three_month_forecast
        ->  Sort  (cost=15074.13..15074.14 rows=1 width=22) (actual time=431.935..431.935 rows=3 loops=1)
              Sort Key: forecasts.month
              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
              ->  HashAggregate  (cost=15074.11..15074.12 rows=1 width=22) (actual time=431.354..431.363 rows=3 loops=1)
                    ->  Seq Scan on forecasts  (cost=0.00..15074.08 rows=3 width=22) (actual time=0.765..431.255 rows=3 loops=1)
                          Filter: (final AND (extract_date >= '2016-07-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (extract_date < '2016-08-01'::date) AND (month >= '2016-08-01'::date) AND (month < '2016-11-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND ((product_number)::text = '100046119'::text))
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 442623
      ->  CTE Scan on three_month_forecast  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=431.959..431.962 rows=3 loops=1)
    Total runtime: 432.513 ms
```

**Final Edit**

@QuoVadis solution worked perfectly. It is so obvious when I looked at the solution. Thanks.

Comment: can you share some sample input and expected output?

Comment: I just added a sqlfiddle sample. It contains data for one product along with the expected output for each product. I am trying to get that result for all the products contained in the products database. Please let me know if that is sufficient.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of `explain (analyze, buffers, timing)` for the query and the definition of all indexes of the table. _Formatted_ text please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: The query takes 400 **milli** seconds (so less then half a second) How fast do you need that to be?

Comment: @Pras, expecting like this ``with three_month_forecast as 
(select product_number, count(id) cnt, sum(quantity) qty from forecasts group by product_number)
select product_number, qty/cnt from three_month_forecast``?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sorry about the miscommunication. I meant to say it takes a long time in Ruby on Rails where I iterate over each product and generate the average forecast. It takes around an hour or two there. I found SQL to be so much faster, which is why I am trying to convert the queries to raw sql.

Comment: @Spike thanks for the help. What you outlined is exactly what I wanted to do with a slight bit of modifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it.

```
WITH three_month_forecast AS (
SELECT product_number, month, sum(quantity) as forecast
FROM forecasts
WHERE extract_date >= '2016-08-01'::DATE - INTERVAL '1 month'
  AND extract_date < '2016-08-01'::DATE
  AND final = TRUE
  AND month >= '2016-08-01'::DATE
  AND month < '2016-08-01'::DATE + INTERVAL '3 months'
  AND product_number in (select distinct product_number from forecasts)
GROUP BY product_number, month, extract_date
ORDER BY month
)
SELECT avg(forecast), product_number FROM three_month_forecast
group by product_number
```

See example [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a87e8/2)

Comment: not that you can provide the list of product_number instead of doing the `select distinct product_number ...` Given that, the answer above will compute all your products averages in one go.